# XSL, How to color a part of string

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

How can i really Color a part of string specially if iam using `<xsl:text>` and `<xsl:value-of>` if i'm transforming them into xsl:fo

for example

```
<xsl:text>this is a string</xsl:text> <xsl:text>string is : </xsl:text> <xsl:value-of select="current()/@string"/>
```

How can I Color this part only:

```
<xsl:text>string is : </xsl:text> <xsl:value-of select="current()/@string"/>
```

Thank you

Comment: That would depend a helluva lot on your output format. What are you transforming to? HTML? XSL:FO? Something else entirely?

Comment: I'm transforming it into xsL:fo to print it as pdf

Comment: What exactly should appear in color? The text inside `xsl:text` or the text content of the `string` attribute you retrieve?

Comment: I would say both of them should be colored in green

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the color of text content in XSL-FO, simply use the `color` attribute of either `fo:block` or `fo:inline`.

```
<fo:block color="green">
  <xsl:text>string is : </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="@string"/>
</fo:block>
```

In most contexts, `@string` means exactly the same as `current()/@string`, so perhaps you can omit the first part. There is also `background-color`, in case you meant to color the background, not the letters themselves.

Find the relevant part of the XSL specification [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#color).